# Correct minified/uglified/revv-ed JS on Windows, but empty file on Linux?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, concatenation, grunt-usemin

I've been pulling my hair lately. I have a Yeoman generated JekyllRB grunt/bower setup. The build works correct on my Windows machine but not on an automated Linux build machine.

With correct, I mean that I get a minified/uglified/revv-ed version of JQuery in

> dist/js/50b6.app.js

On the continuous integration build setup, which runs Linux, I get an empty js file:

> dist/js/d41d.app.js

I updated Grunt and all plugins to the latest version, without success. Analyzed my full Gruntfile.js, verified the src and dest of all the plugins and all seems the same, taking into account the difference in platform specific path separators.

Here is the link to the sources of my Jekyll site: [site-ringo](https://bitbucket.org/ringods/site-ringo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I was able to resolve this myself. I hadn't updated my local Bower components for a while. On my build server, I ended up with another version of JQuery than on my local machine. The newer JQuery was packaged differently leading to the jquery.js file being in another location. As such, the concat+uglify+rev build chain didn't pick up the correct file leading to the output file being empty.